# How to merge two columns from CASE STATEMENT of DIFFERENT CONDITION

Tags: sql, case, sql-server-2014

My expected result should be like

```
----invoiceNo----
T17080003,INV14080011
```

But right now, I've come up with following query.

```
SELECT AccountDoc.jobCode,AccountDoc.shipmentSyskey,AccountDoc.docType,    
    CASE AccountDoc.docType
    WHEN 'M' THEN
    JobInvoice.invoiceNo
    WHEN 'I' THEN
    (STUFF((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(CAST(AccountDoc.docNo AS VARCHAR(20)))
     FROM AccountDoc LEFT OUTER JOIN JobInvoice
     ON AccountDoc.principalCode = JobInvoice.principalCode AND 
     AccountDoc.jobCode = JobInvoice.jobCode
     WHERE (AccountDoc.isCancelledByCN = 0)
          AND (AccountDoc.docType = 'I')
          AND (AccountDoc.jobCode = @jobCode)
          AND (AccountDoc.shipmentSyskey = @shipmentSyskey)
          AND (AccountDoc.principalCode = @principalCode) FOR XML 
          PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' '))
    END AS invoiceNo

FROM AccountDoc LEFT OUTER JOIN JobInvoice
ON JobInvoice.principalCode = AccountDoc.principalCode AND 
JobInvoice.jobCode = AccountDoc.jobCode
WHERE (AccountDoc.jobCode = @jobCode)
        AND (AccountDoc.isCancelledByCN = 0)
        AND (AccountDoc.shipmentSyskey = @shipmentSyskey)
        AND (AccountDoc.principalCode = @principalCode)
```

OUTPUT:

```
----invoiceNo----
T17080003
INV14080011
```

Explanation:

I want to select docNo from table AccountDoc if `AccountDoc.docType = I`.
Or select invoiceNo from table JobInvoice if `AccountDoc.docType = M`.

The problem is what if under same jobCode there have 2 docType which are M and I, how I gonna display these 2 invoices?

Comment: where do you use your query result after? in Excel? just do the presentation part in the next step, not in sql.

Comment: Mind if I edit your post so it's not so messed up looking?

Comment: @StevenBENET I use sql server, and I will put inside report (Mic. Visual Studio)

Comment: @CaiusJard yes please, feel free to edit this post :)

Comment: @intanshafienaz microsoft visual studio is not a reporting solution ... and i believe your report solution should be able to do this step more easily than in sql which is not made for that

Comment: @StevenBENET I mean the output will be display inside that report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using CTE and FOR XML. below is the sample code i created using similar tables you have -

```
Create table #AccountDoc (
id  int ,
docType char(1),
docNo  varchar(10)
)

Create table #JobInvoice (
id  int ,
invoiceNo varchar(10)
)

insert into #AccountDoc
select 1 , 'M' ,'M1234'   
union all  select 2 , 'M' ,'M2345' 
union all  select 3 , 'M' ,'M3456' 
union all  select 4 , 'I' ,'I1234' 
union all  select 5 , 'I' ,'I2345' 
union all  select 6 , 'I' ,'I3456' 

insert into #JobInvoice
select 1 , 'INV1234'   
union all  select 2 , 'INV2345' 
union all  select 3 ,  'INV3456' 

select  * 
from #AccountDoc t1 left join #JobInvoice t2
on t1.id = t2.id  

with cte as
(
select isnull(  case  t1.docType  WHEN 'M' THEN t2.invoiceNo   WHEN 'I' then 
t1.docNo   end  ,'') invoiceNo
from #AccountDoc t1 left join #JobInvoice t2
on t1.id = t2.id  )
select invoiceNo + ',' from cte  For XML PATH ('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot your data if you have situations where there are two rows, and you want two columns. Your sql is a bit messy, particularly the bit where you put an entire select statement inside a case when in the select part of another query. These two queries are virtually the same, you should look for a more optimal way of writing them. However, you can wrap your entire sql in the following:

```
select
    Jobcode, shipmentsyskey, [M],[I]
from(

  --YOUR ENTIRE SQL GOES HERE BETWEEN THESE BRACKETS. Do not alter anything else, just paste your entire sql here

) yoursql
pivot(
 max(invoiceno)
 for docType in([M],[I])
)pvt
```

Comment: thanks for helping me but I didnt get a clear solution, can you please edit from my sql as well ? please..

Comment: I didn't understand your request..  just take the sql I wrote, copy paste your sql into it at the point I indicated with --YOUR ENTIRE SQL... and run the resulting query. If there's something you didn't understand about how it works, let me know. I'm here to teach you how to do things, not do your work for you

Comment: i just want to concate both invoiceNo tht I got from this sql

Comment: If you run it you'll see that you get two columns called m and I, these are your doctypes, if you have an invoice for both doctypes, then your sql would produce a row for each. My sql produces one row with a column for each.. its what you requested,

Comment: You're going to have to put more effort in than 'I got an error'. I'm not a mind reader, nor can I see your screen and magically know what error you got..

Comment: I never use pivot before, so that y im a bit blank,

Comment: there's a first time for everything :)

Comment: so by using pivot I can get output like "T17080003,INV14080011" ?

Comment: ok status for now, I success make it as one row, then how can I merge the invoices?

Comment: You mean you want a single column? That's string concatenation, unfortunately an ugly thing  to do in sqls2008.. change the select list to: `jobcode, shipmentsyskey, COALESCE(m,'')+CASE WHEN M IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END+COALESCE(I,'') as concatenatedinvoices`

Comment: Ps: that part you should have been able to do yourself, if you can write a complicated query like you have, then concatenation strings together is very elementary sql. If it's new to you, you should do some background research into basic sql stuff when you have some time

Comment: I can do it if the docType is same, but in this case docType is different